# Invalid Resx File. Resourcetypecode.stream cannot be located

Tags: resources, invalidation

```
</data>
  <assembly alias="System.Windows.Forms" name="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <data name="HeyStop" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>HeyStop;ResourceTypeCode.Stream</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Flute" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>Flute;ResourceTypeCode.Stream</value>
  </data>
  <data name="alert" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>alert;ResourceTypeCode.Stream</value>
  </data>
```

error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. Type ResourceTypeCode.Stream cannot be located. Line 270, position 5.

Comment: Please, describe your problem.

Comment: That's just it. I don't know the problem. The error shows up on the first </data> line.